# Sharing sound devices between Linux and Windows machines

Tags: windows, linux, audio, networking

I am looking for a software capable to share sound output devices on an ipv4 network.

Is it somehow possible?

- Ideally, I would like to hear the sound of a Windows machine on a Linux box. But the other direction is also ok.
- I need sound output, but if I can also share input devices, it is better.

Comment: So you wish to hear a music played on a windows machine on both a windows machine and a Linux machine?

Comment: @AswinPJ Both cases are okay, but the Windows -> Linux direction is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way that you may be able to accomplish what you want, it requires two different pieces of software. This method is for sending sound from your **Windows PC to Linux**. First, you need software called "**Stream What You Hear**" installed on your Windows PC. This will allow you to stream the sound from your Windows PC to a UPnP/DLNA device. You will then install UPNP / DLNA client on Linux. I recommend using software called VLC. To use VLC start the Playlist (`View` -> `Playlist`; `Ctrl + L`) and then select `Local Network` -> `Universal Plug 'n' Play` - [Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/109083/486617).

## [Stream What You Hear](http://www.streamwhatyouhear.com/) (free)

> Stream What You Hear (SWYH) is a Windows application to broadcast the sound of your computer (ie: “what you hear”) on an UPnP/DLNA device such as TVs, amps, network receivers, game consoles, etc...

## [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) (free)

> VLC is a free and open source cross-platform multimedia player and framework that plays most multimedia files as well as DVDs, Audio CDs, VCDs, and various streaming protocols.

#### Edit 1

As Steve pointed out, it may also be possible to send streams as well as receiving them just using VLC.

Comment: Note that VLC is also available on Windows and can stream media content, (audio & video), including capture from things like microphone/webcam from __both__ Windows and Linux as well as receiving such streams.